# What is sync_replicas in Tensorflow object-detection?

Tags: tensorflow

I google online on what sync_replica is and this is what I found

```
 // Whether to synchronize replicas during training.

  optional bool sync_replicas = 3 [default=false]
```

I noticed that it have something to do with using multiple GPU to train the object-detection model but I have no idea what does "Whether to synchronize replicas during training mean"

Comment: same. It seems to be something to do w/ asynchronous training: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SyncReplicasOptimizer